# How to Send Mail to Multi Recipient With Multi SMPT'S?

Tags: c#, email, smtp, mailkit

Hello to all the master I am new to C# and trying to make a mail sender which can send e mails to many recipient with a bunch of SMTP'S , USING SMTP'S one by one To send them messages

THE CODE I AM USING TO DO SO!!

```
       private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Timeout = 30000;
        client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");



        BodyBuilder builder = new BodyBuilder();
        builder.HtmlBody = textBoxHTMLBody.Text;


        MimeMessage mail = new MimeMessage();
        mail.Subject = textBoxSubject.Text;
        mail.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();


        client.Connect(textBoxSMTP.Text, int.Parse(textBoxPORT.Text), CheckBoxSSL.Checked);
        client.Authenticate(textBoxUser.Text, textBoxPassword.Text);
        
       

        foreach (string email  in listBoxEMails.Items)
        {



            mail.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("hello", textBoxUser.Text));
            mail.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("",email));
            client.Send(mail);


            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }



        client.Disconnect(true);



    }
```

this is the code i am using for sending mails from only one smtp and i am stuck , that how can i send e mails  with many SMTP'S

[image: THIS THE THE IMAGE FOR THE SMTP SETUP]

By using data grid I created this form and I want to send E MAILS USING Datagridview1 data

means instead of using text box . I want to use each Row as smtp data from data grid as server , port , user and pass for smtp in above code.
What should be the changes to make it real

Thanks to all the masters in advance !!!

Comment: Are you using MailKit? Which version of C#, you have tagged two?

Comment: yes master i am using mailkit  will you please help me how can i complete this because i am suffering from this from last 3 days

Comment: What do you mean by "stuck"? Your window does not respond?

Comment: I am stuck to do soo means i want to send each mail with one by one with different smtp from data grid , what should i make changes to code to do soo